# using subquery's column alias as a property in main query

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, alias

i want to know if the main query can see the alias, here's an example:

```
SELECT AVG(values)
FROM(
  SELECT SUM(a1) AS values
  FROM tableX
)
```

Does the first query see the alias "values"?

Comment: `values` is a bad example as it's a keyword and might make trouble, so you might want to use another alias. But have you just tried if it works for yourself? What have you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the first query see the alias "values"?

Yes, it does. The subquery creates a *derived table*, and aliases act as column names in that context. However, standard SQL requires that you give an alias to the subquery.

So:

```
SELECT AVG(vals)
FROM(
    SELECT SUM(a1) AS vals
    FROM tableX
) t --> alias of the subquery
```

Side notes:

- `values` is a language keyword, hence not a good choice for a column name; I renamed it to `vals` in the query
- Your example is really contrived; the subquery always returns one row, so aggregating again in the outer query makes little sense: this is guaranteed to return the same value as that of the subquery. A more useful example would put a `group by` clause in the subquery, like so

```
SELECT AVG(vals)
FROM(
    SELECT SUM(a1) AS vals
    FROM tableX
    GROUP BY id
) t
```

Comment: ty for the advices :)

Comment: yes, the group by is needed, i simplified the problem focussing only on the alias